# sed not catching the expected text

Tags: sed, git

I am working with the git filter branch for one specific task. It is using the sed command. When I use simple regex everything is working but for something more complex it is not. Maybe I have mistake in the regex or in the escaping chars. Please help.

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed -e "s/\[PEM-2233\] Merge branch 'master' of https:\/\/bitbucket\.test\.domain\.com\/rrr\/pem\/hello-world into feature\/PEM-2233-do-acceptance-tests/CHANGED/"' -- --all
```

The commit message I am trying to catch is

```
[PEM-2233] Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.test.domain.com/rrr/pem/hello-world into feature/PEM-2233-do-acceptance-tests
```

Comment: change sed subcommand separator to `#`

Comment: not so pro at it, what is the command for changing? or just sed -e "s#regex#replacement#g"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest single quotes. The single quote before `master` closes the quoted string starting after `--msg-filter`.

As you can't include single quotes in a single quoted string, you need to end the string and properly escape the quotes:

```
branch '\'master\'' of http
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue are the single quotes around `'master'`.  The first of these quotes will end the single quoted string that starts with `sed -e`.  The quotes themselves will not be passed on to `sed`.

It's equivalent to the issue with

```
$ echo '"hello 'user'"'
"hello user"
```

Change the quoting to

- `'\'master\''` (the string `'master'` will be seen as an unquoted string by the shell), or
- `'"'master'"'` (the string `'master'` will be seen as a double quoted string by the shell).

Also, to avoid [the leaning toothpick-syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome), use another delimiter for the `s` command:

```
s#...#...#
```